# What happens after the ancilla is measured in a parity measurement?

Tags: error-correction, measurement

Measurement of qubits results in collapsing the wavefunction/state in $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. I have a doubt about Parity Measurement ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_measurement#:%7E:text=Parity%20Measurement%20in%20Quantum%20Error%20Correction)).

We entangle physical qubits with ancilla qubits by $\text{CNOT}$ gates, and then we measure ancilla qubits and then apply correction gate based on the measurement values of ancilla qubits.

I doubt that if other qubits are entangled with ancilla, if we measure ancilla, other qubits state should also collapse, resulting in losing the original state.

Comment: Have you tried simulating it or calculating it?